# Wamp phpmyadmin error #2002 after moving live site to local

Tags: mysql

I copied over a live Wordpress site to my local wamp server for theme development. However after I got it up and running, once I shut down Wamp and start it again, the icon is orange because phpmyadmin isn't working with a #2002 error.

I'm not super knowledgeable about this stuff so it would be great to get some help interpreting the error log to solve the problem:

```
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 1625977
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: fb218c3f-3b3a-11e6-9517-305a3a7dfc8e.
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2016-06-25 18:11:58 7540 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.17'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2016-06-25 19:20:52 104c InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:20:52 104c InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:20:52 104c InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:22:07 15d4 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:22:07 15d4 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "local"."wp_links" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:27:52 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:36:01 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:36:01 1288 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2016-06-25 19:36:01 1288 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "local"."wp_termmeta" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] wampmysqld: Arrêt normal du serveur

2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Binlog end
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-06-25 19:37:54 7540 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2890038
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-06-25 19:37:55 7540 [Note] wampmysqld: Arrêt du serveur terminé

2016-06-25 19:37:58 6148 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
wampmysqld: La table 'mysql.plugin' n'existe pas
2016-06-25 19:37:58 6148 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2016-06-25 19:37:58 6148 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-25 19:37:58 6148 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-25 19:37:58 6148 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-25 19:37:58 6148 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-25 19:37:58 6148 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-06-25 19:37:58 6148 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-06-25 19:37:58 6148 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-25 19:37:58 6148 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-25 19:37:59 6148 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-25 19:37:59 6148 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-06-25 19:37:59 6148 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 2890038
2016-06-25 19:37:59 6148 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2016-06-25 19:37:59 6148 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2016-06-25 19:37:59 6148 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2016-06-25 19:37:59 6148 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-25 19:37:59 6148 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: La table 'mysql.user' n'existe pas
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you done? Copied the `MySQL` binaries? You are missing relevant tables (`mysql.user`). To repair this frist try [mysql_upgrade](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html), If not solved use [mysql_install_db](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-install-db.html). Backup before! To copy a `MySQL Database` use export and import ( e.g.:  from `pma` or `Workbench`.).

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I deleted the mysql database by mistake. I reinstalled wamp againt and its all good.